# Plot the bar legend instead of ranges when using quantiles scheme in geopandas plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

Let's say I have the data and I use geopandas plot function to create the following map

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap = 'Blues', scheme='quantiles', k = 10,legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you see it generates the legend with the range values. Is it possible to change this legend and plot the standard bar legend with different (sequantial) colours?

I know that the quantiles scheme creates the classes and you can't treat them as a continuous variable, but somehow it should still be possible to construct a bar legend similar to one when I delete `scheme='quantiles', k = 10` from the code above.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap = 'Set1', legend=True)`, you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still want to include a quantiles scheme in my code. So if I do that, the legend is still with ranges and not a bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `qualitative colormap` is needed for a thematic plot, one can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGgrM.png). I select `tab10` for use in the code below.

To get a specific colormap's discrete items that match the number of required (10) classes, the colormap needs to be `resampled` before use.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
# GPD per capita x 1000
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est * 1000

# Prep special colormap to match the number of classes
num_classes = 10
color_steps = plt.colormaps['tab10']._resample(num_classes)

# This plots polygons
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap = color_steps, 
           scheme='quantiles', k = num_classes,
           legend=True, 
           legend_kwds={'loc':'upper right', 
                        'bbox_to_anchor':(1.23, 1.01), 
                        'fmt':'{:.3f}',
                        'markerscale':1.26, 
                        'title_fontsize':'medium', 
                        'fontsize':'small'}, 
           ax=ax)

leg1 = ax.get_legend()
# Set markers to square shape
for ea in leg1.legendHandles:
    ea.set_marker('s')
leg1.set_title("GPD per capita x1000")
ax.title.set_text("World Map: GPD per Capita")
plt.show()
```

[image: plot1]

If `sequential colormap` is used instead of `qualitative colormap`, the plot can be created similarly. Here I use `Blues` colormap. This is more appropriate for the GDP per capita data.

[image: newPlot2]

**EDIT**
My apology for some errors on the code/map:-
GPD ---> GDP

The legend's label texts can be accessed and edited as needed.
Additional code for such operation follows:-

```
# Manipulate the legend's label texts
# Replace range_text with mid_range as new label texts
for eb in leg1.get_texts():
    txt = eb.get_text()
    low,high = [float(tt) for tt in  txt.split(sep=",")]
    avg = (low+high)/2        # compute mid-range values
    #print(low,high,avg)
    eb.set_text(f"{avg:.2f}") # midrange values, 2 deci digits
    #eb.set_text(f"")         # blank-out text
```

The changes will be:

```
Old text         --> New text
  0.570,   1.655 --> 1.11
  1.655,   3.053 --> 2.35
  3.053,   4.813 --> 3.93
  4.813,   8.357 --> 6.58
  8.357,  11.620 --> 9.99
 11.620,  15.776 --> 13.70
 15.776,  24.574 --> 20.18
 24.574,  35.761 --> 30.17
 35.761,  48.513 --> 42.14
 48.513, 200.000 --> 124.26
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is a huge help. One additional question. It still produces the ranges in legend. Is it possible to produce some kind of bar as a legend?

Comment: @AvtoAbashishvili The `ranges` texts can be edited/deleted. See the additional code in the answer.