# Customize colorbar ticklabels for a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I would like to customize the colorbar tickmarks on a heatmap and make them more descriptive (and not just 0, 1. 2, 3).

I have created the heatmap from data that looks like the below:

| index | Entity | Code | Year | nuclear_weapons_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4433 | Egypt | EGY | 1951 | 0 |
| 272 | Algeria | DZA | 1955 | 0 |
| 16119 | United States | USA | 1976 | 3 |
| 13954 | Spain | ESP | 1949 | 0 |
| 775 | Australia | AUS | 1948 | 0 |
| 5218 | France | FRA | 1971 | 3 |
| 13977 | Spain | ESP | 1972 | 0 |
| 11850 | Portugal | PRT | 2016 | 0 |
| 12805 | Saudi Arabia | SAU | 2014 | 0 |
| 2044 | Brazil | BRA | 1942 | 0 |
| 116 | Afghanistan | AFG | 1969 | 0 |
| 640 | Argentina | ARG | 1983 | 1 |
| 6793 | Iraq | IRQ | 1974 | 0 |
| 6820 | Iraq | IRQ | 2001 | 0 |
| 12056 | Russia | RUS | 1945 | 2 |
| 13611 | South Africa | ZAF | 1970 | 1 |
| 16019 | United Kingdom | GBR | 1961 | 3 |
| 6987 | Israel | ISR | 1998 | 3 |
| 9440 | Mexico | MEX | 1986 | 0 |
| 268 | Algeria | DZA | 1951 | 0 |

This is my code with various attempts to add descriptive colorbar or legend but none has been successful so far.

```
g = country_position_df.pivot('Entity', 'Year', 'nuclear_weapons_status')
plt.figure(figsize=(40,20));
sns.heatmap(g, linewidth=.5, cmap= colors, cbar_kws={'ticks': ticks, 'boundaries': boundaries, 'label': print(labels)});
plt.title("Country position on nuclear weapons, 1938 to 2022");
plt.ylabel("Country");
plt.xlabel("Year");
plt.legend({0: 'Not', 1:'Cons', 2:'Pur', 3:'Pos'});

plt.show()
```

This is what I am getting:
[image]

Comment: You can always access the legend's labels and change them. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74013201/plot-the-bar-legend-instead-of-ranges-when-using-quantiles-scheme-in-geopandas-p/74021195#74021195

Comment: @cav Your post is missing the values for a.o. `ticks`, `boundaries` and `labels`. Note that `'label': print(labels)` puts the return value `None` into `label`.  Further, as there are no elements with legend labels, `plt.legend()`  puts an empty legend into the plot (the strange white mark at the top left).

Comment: With `ax = sns.heatmap(....)`, `c_bar = ax.collections[0].colorbar` and  `c_bar.set_ticklabels(['Not','Cons','Pur', 'Pos'])` your code might work.  Note that in Python, you shouldn't write semicolons at the end of commands (except possibly after the very last command if you are working with a Jupyter notebook).